# How to prove decidability of a partial order inductive predicate?

Tags: coq, proof, deterministic, formal-verification, partial-ordering

## Context

I am trying to define the partial order A ≤ B ≤ C with a relation `le` in Coq and prove that it is decidable: `forall x y, {le x y} + {~le x y}`.

I succeeded to do it through an equivalent boolean function `leb` but cannot find a way to prove it directly (or `le_antisym` for that mater). I get stuck in situations like the following:

```
1 subgoal
H : le C A
______________________________________(1/1)
False
```

## Questions

1. How can I prove, that `le C A` is a false premise?
2. Is there an other other proof strategy that I should use?
3. Should I define my predicate `le` differently?

## Minimal executable example

```
Require Import Setoid.

Ltac inv H := inversion H; clear H; subst.

Inductive t : Set := A | B | C.

Ltac destruct_ts :=
  repeat match goal with
  | [ x : t |- _ ] => destruct x
  end.

Inductive le : t -> t -> Prop :=
  | le_refl : forall x, le x x
  | le_trans : forall x y z, le x y -> le y z -> le x z
  | le_A_B : le A B
  | le_B_C : le B C .

Definition leb (x y : t) : bool :=
  match x, y with
  | A, _ => true
  | _, C => true
  | B, B => true
  | _, _ => false
  end.

Theorem le_iff_leb : forall x y,
  le x y <-> leb x y = true.
Proof.
  intros x y. split; intro H.
  - induction H; destruct_ts; simpl in *; congruence.
  - destruct_ts; eauto using le; simpl in *; congruence.
Qed.

Theorem le_antisym : forall x y,
  le x y -> le y x -> x = y.
Proof.
  intros x y H1 H2.
  rewrite le_iff_leb in *. (* How to prove that without using [leb]? *)
  destruct x, y; simpl in *; congruence.
Qed.

Theorem le_dec : forall x y, { le x y } + { ~le x y }.
  intros x y.
  destruct x, y; eauto using le.
  - apply right.
    intros H. (* Stuck here *)
    inv H.
    rewrite le_iff_leb in *.
    destruct y; simpl in *; congruence.
  - apply right.
    intros H; inv H. (* Same thing *)
    rewrite le_iff_leb in *.
    destruct y; simpl in *; congruence.
  - apply right.
    intros H; inv H. (* Same thing *)
    rewrite le_iff_leb in *.
    destruct y; simpl in *; congruence.
Qed.
```

Comment: Why do you call this a partial ordering? There are three elements A | B | C and they're totally ordered.

Comment: This is the simplest example I could come with but the relation I am working on is not a total order, so I did not want someone to come up with an answer dependent on the fact that the order is total.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with `le` is the transitivity constructor: when doing inversion or induction on a proof of `le x y`, we know nothing about the middle point that comes out of the transitivity case, which often leads to failed proof attempts.  You can prove your result with an alternative (but still inductive) characterization of the relation:

```
Require Import Setoid.

Ltac inv H := inversion H; clear H; subst.

Inductive t : Set := A | B | C.

Inductive le : t -> t -> Prop :=
  | le_refl : forall x, le x x
  | le_trans : forall x y z, le x y -> le y z -> le x z
  | le_A_B : le A B
  | le_B_C : le B C .

Inductive le' : t -> t -> Prop :=
  | le'_refl : forall x, le' x x
  | le'_A_B  : le' A B
  | le'_B_C  : le' B C
  | le'_A_C  : le' A C.

Lemma le_le' x y : le x y <-> le' x y.
Proof.
  split.
  - intros H.
    induction H as [x|x y z xy IHxy yz IHyz| | ]; try now constructor.
    inv IHxy; inv IHyz; constructor.
  - intros H; inv H; eauto using le.
Qed.

Theorem le_antisym : forall x y,
  le x y -> le y x -> x = y.
Proof.
  intros x y.
  rewrite 2!le_le'.
  intros []; trivial; intros H; inv H.
Qed.

Theorem le_dec : forall x y, { le x y } + { ~le x y }.
  intros x y.
  destruct x, y; eauto using le; right; rewrite le_le';
  intros H; inv H.
Qed.
```

In this case, however, I think that using an inductive characterization of `le` is not a good idea, because the boolean version is more useful.  Naturally, there are occasions where you would like two characterizations of a relation: for instance, sometimes you would like a boolean test for equality on a type, but would like to use `=` for rewriting.  The [ssreflect proof language](https://github.com/math-comp/math-comp) makes it easy to work in this style.  For instance, here is another version of your first proof attempt.  (The `reflect P b` predicate means that the proposition `P` is equivalent to the assertion `b = true`.)

```
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool.

Inductive t : Set := A | B | C.

Inductive le : t -> t -> Prop :=
  | le_refl : forall x, le x x
  | le_trans : forall x y z, le x y -> le y z -> le x z
  | le_A_B : le A B
  | le_B_C : le B C .

Definition leb (x y : t) : bool :=
  match x, y with
  | A, _ => true
  | _, C => true
  | B, B => true
  | _, _ => false
  end.

Theorem leP x y : reflect (le x y) (leb x y).
Proof.
apply/(iffP idP); first by case: x; case y=> //=; eauto using le.
by elim=> [[]| | |] //= [] [] [].
Qed.

Theorem le_antisym x y : le x y -> le y x -> x = y.
Proof. by case: x; case: y; move=> /leP ? /leP ?. Qed.

Theorem le_dec : forall x y, { le x y } + { ~le x y }.
Proof. by move=> x y; case: (leP x y); eauto. Qed.
```

Comment: Beat me to it, with the exact same `le'`.

Comment: @Yves just did it here and there.

Comment: So the `le'` basically enumerate the cases handled by the pattern matching in `leb`? Doesn't it lead to a number of cases *O(n)* in the amount *n* of elements? I was hoping to avoid it by getting rid `leb`...

Comment: @authchir yes, that is what it does. I don't think you can avoid this growth; if you were to generalize `le`, you would still need to mention each constructor at least once.

Answer (score 2):

I'd also go with Arthur's solution. But let me demonstrate another approach.

First, we'll need a couple of supporting lemmas:

```
Lemma not_leXA x : x <> A -> ~ le x A.
Proof. remember A; intros; induction 1; subst; firstorder congruence. Qed.

Lemma not_leCX x : x <> C -> ~ le C x.
Proof. remember C; intros; induction 1; subst; firstorder congruence. Qed.
```

Now we can define `le_dec`:

```
Definition le_dec x y : { le x y } + { ~le x y }.
Proof.
  destruct x, y; try (left; abstract constructor).
  - left; abstract (eapply le_trans; constructor).
  - right; abstract now apply not_leXA.
  - right; abstract now apply not_leCX.
  - right; abstract now apply not_leCX.
Defined.
```

Notice that I used `Defined` instead of `Qed` -- now you can calculate with  `le_dec`, which is usually the point of using the `sumbool` type.

I also used `abstract` to conceal the proof terms from the evaluator. E.g. let's imagine I defined a `le_dec'` function which is the same as `le_dec`, but with all `abstract` removed, then we would get the following results when trying to compute `le_dec B A` / `le_dec' B A` :

```
Compute le_dec B A.
(* ==> right le_dec_subproof5 *)
```

and

```
Compute le_dec' B A.
(* ==> right
     (not_leXA B
        (fun x : B = A =>
         match x in (_ = x0) return (x0 = A -> False) with
         | eq_refl =>
             fun x0 : B = A =>
             match
               match
                 x0 in (_ = x1)
                 return match x1 with
                        | B => True
                        | _ => False
                        end
               with
               | eq_refl => I
               end return False
             with
             end
         end eq_refl)) *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can make use of the definitions in `Relations` to define your order relation. For instance, it contains a definition of reflexive and transitive closure named `clos_refl_trans`. The resulting proofs are similar to those based on your definitions (cf. @Anton's answer).

```
Require Import Relations.

Inductive t : Set := A | B | C.

Inductive le : t -> t -> Prop :=
  | le_A_B : le A B
  | le_B_C : le B C.

Definition le' := clos_refl_trans _ le.

Lemma A_minimal : forall x, x <> A -> ~ le' x A.
Proof.
  intros. intros contra. remember A as a. induction contra; subst.
  - inversion H0.
  - contradiction.
  - destruct y; apply IHcontra2 + apply IHcontra1; congruence.
Qed.

Lemma C_maximal : forall x, x <> C -> ~ le' C x.
Proof.
  intros. intros contra. remember C as c. induction contra; subst.
  - inversion H0.
  - contradiction.
  - destruct y; apply IHcontra2 + apply IHcontra1; congruence.
Qed.

Lemma le'_antisym : forall x y,
  le' x y -> le' y x -> x = y.
Proof.
  intros. induction H.
  - destruct H.
    + apply A_minimal in H0; try discriminate. contradiction.
    + apply C_maximal in H0; try discriminate. contradiction.
  - reflexivity.
  - fold le' in *. rewrite IHclos_refl_trans1 by (eapply rt_trans; eassumption).
    apply IHclos_refl_trans2; (eapply rt_trans; eassumption).
Qed.
```